# Python Pygame Event List double enties and very long

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

Okay, i am using Python3 with an Ubuntu Linux OS.
I have a very simple bot which moves when i press a arrow key. My problem is that when I read in the pygame event list it contains 328 elements of the same key pressing down. Therefore I am not able to change direction with my bot because I get the signal not once I get it 328 times. Is there any solution for the problem.
My code looks like this:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for key in keys:
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.map.move(self.map.x1 - 1, self.map.y1 + 0)

        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.map.move(self.map.x1 + 1, self.map.y1 + 0)

        elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.map.move(self.map.x1 + 0, self.map.y1 + 1)

        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.map.move(self.map.x1 + 0, self.map.y1 - 1)
```

The x1 and y1 are the coordinates of my robot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If might be more convenient to handle the key down events in the event handler:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.map.move(self.map.x1 - 1, self.map.y1 + 0)
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.map.move(self.map.x1 + 1, self.map.y1 + 0)
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            self.map.move(self.map.x1 + 0, self.map.y1 + 1)
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            self.map.move(self.map.x1 + 0, self.map.y1 - 1)
```

This should prevent handling a single key press more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to loop over the pressed keys. Just remove `for key in keys:` and move the sequence of `if ... elif` outside the event loop.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()

keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    self.map.move(self.map.x1 - 1, self.map.y1 + 

elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    self.map.move(self.map.x1 + 1, self.map.y1 + 0)

elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
    self.map.move(self.map.x1 + 0, self.map.y1 + 1)

elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
    self.map.move(self.map.x1 + 0, self.map.y1 - 1)
```

`pygame.key.get_pressed()` checks which keys are pressed when the function is called, you usually want to call it once per main loop, but definitely not in the loop checking for events.

Comment: yes, basically you are right but my key list contains 328 elements, so i would still double it. (i have checked it with print(len(keys)))

Comment: `pygame.key.get_pressed()` does not return a list, but a dictionary mapping every key of your keyboard to a boolean value. `True` if that key is pressed, `False` if that key is not pressed. You just need to check the keys you are interested, and this is what you are doing with `if keys[...]`. Ths is useful if you want to achieve the effect of moving the bot keeping the key pressed